# UIWebView not loading a new url

Tags: ios, swift, webview, swift3

Everytime I try to load another URL on a UIWebView i get the same error:

> SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds.

My code about the webView is like:

```
@IBAction func changeUrl(sender: UIButton) {
    if LEDON {
        let urlStr = NSString(format: "%@/?Led=0", self.url)
        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr as String)!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        while(webView.isLoading) {
            sender.isEnabled = false
        }
        sender.isEnabled = true
        LEDON = false;
    } else {
        let urlStr = NSString(format: "%@/?Led=1", self.url)
        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr as String)!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        while(webView.isLoading) {
           sender.isEnabled = false
        }
        sender.isEnabled = true
        LEDON = true;
    }
}
```

If I press the UIButton the first time the code works perfectly, but when I tap it again I get that error. 
Where am I doing wrong?

"url" variable in the code is a global var and I already check that is correct.

Comment: You don't need use this while(webView.isLoading) {sender.isEnabled = false}. You have frozen main thread and application cannot responding for any requests. You need use delegate methods for this.

Comment: But when the while loop finished the sender is again  active. When I call the action again the webView doesn't load, but the button works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in

```
while(webView.isLoading) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
}
```

You have frozen main thread and **webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:** can't be invoke.

Try to use this:

```
func viewDidLoad()
{
    ...
    webView.delegate = self;//UIWebView
    //webView. navigationDelegate = self;//WKWebView
}

@IBAction func changeUrl(sender: UIButton) {
    if LEDON {
        let urlStr = NSString(format: "%@/?Led=0", self.url)
        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr as String)!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        sender.isEnabled = false
        LEDON = false;
    } else {
        let urlStr = NSString(format: "%@/?Led=1", self.url)
        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr as String)!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        sender.isEnabled = false
        LEDON = true;
    }
}
```

For UIWebView you need to use

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(UIWebView)
{
    yourButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

For WKWebView

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
            didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
    yourButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

**======================================**

If you want use while loop try to change it for this:

```
while(webView.isLoading) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow http and https on your app :

In your info.plist :

> In Info.plist file add a dictionary with key 'NSAppTransportSecurity'
>
> Add another element inside dictionary with key 'Allow Arbitrary Loads'

[image]

Comment: Already done! The first time the url is correctly loaded. The problem is every other time